# ASUS RT-AC66U custom DNS server

Tags: router

I am trying to setup a custom DNS server located on a separate computer using the ASUS RT-AC66U router. I tried installing ASUSWTR-merlin custom firmware with no success, still stuck on regular firmware.

What settings do I need to get the DNS server working.

Under the `WAN Internet Connection` tab I have `WAN DNS Setting`, "connect to DNS Server automatically" set to NO and `DNS Server1` pointing to an internal address `192.168.0.150` and `DNS Server2` pointing to `8.8.8.8` Googles DNS Server. Which seems to not be working.

Under `LAN DHCP Server`, I do have the DHCP server enabled, and the "DNS and WINS Server Setting" DNS Server pointing to `192.168.0.150` as well. Again no success.

Comment: try restarting the network service on your client to refresh this infromation from the router, secondly, make sure that the clients themselves do not have a static dns server set.

Comment: What is 192.168.0.150, is that your router IP?  You don't have to specify that, if you leave LAN DHCP Server DNS blank it will forward perform dns caching and forward lookups to the DNS you specified for the WAN.

Answer (score 1):

To set the DNS on your ASUS router, navigate to **WAN** > **WAN DNS Setting**.

Enter the following values:

```
DNS Server 1: 8.8.8.8
DNS Server 2: 8.8.4.4
```

Then Apply your settings.

All computers and devices connected to this router should now use your new DNS settings.

Note: Once you make these changes, devices already connected to the router (before the changes were made) will need to wait until the Lease Time Expires or until they get the new settings before they can start using them. On windows machines you can use `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /renew` to force the machine to renew its connection.

Comment: The user should also disable the LAN DHCP Server setting DNS (192.168.0.150) he specified.  Leaving that blank, will perform dns caching at the router (clients would receive the router address from DHCP and the router would DNS lookup 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Comment: This is most probably not what OP wanted. The intention is to disable the DNS server on the outer completely, using then a separate machine to resolve these requests. The actual public nameserver would then be configured on the separate machine, not on the router. The router should merely push the address of the local DNS server to dhcp clients.